# Homebrew & brew doctor -

Tags: node.js, homebrew, brew-doctor

Installed Homebrew followed by node.js. Ran **brew doctor** and got the return below.  Tried to find an answer but nothing specifically related.  Any help would be appreciated.  Thanks.

```
    Error: Could not symlink bin/node
    Target /usr/local/bin/node
    already exists. You may want to remove it:
    rm '/usr/local/bin/node'

    To force the link and overwrite all conflicting files:
    brew link --overwrite node

    To list all files that would be deleted:
    brew link --overwrite --dry-run node
```

Comment: The error is saying you already have Node installed (perhaps via the OSX `.pkg`). For homebrew to install Node, it would have to replace the existing installation. And, since it considers that possibly destructive, it won't do so without you instructing it to `--overwrite`.

Comment: @JonathanLonowski you should write this in an answer.

Comment: @JonathanLonowski thank you sir, appreciate the quick response.  I’ll heed your advice and proceed accordingly.